# lstlisting url broken by line wrapping

Tags: listings, line-breaking, urls

I have a URL which get's broken by the line break. Ideally I'd like it to be possible to copy the whole wget command and paste it into a terminal. Unfortunately I am ending with an overflowing box and multiple pieces.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }


\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
linkcolor = blue,
urlcolor  = blue,
citecolor = blue,
anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\newcommand{\MYhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}%
\usepackage{listings, lstautogobble, xcolor, beramono}
\usepackage{tikz}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
columns=flexible,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=false,
backgroundcolor=\color{blue!20},
showstringspaces=false,
frameround=ffff,
frame=single,
rulecolor=\color{black},
autogobble=true}

 \lstset{
emph=[1]{%  
    wget, gunzip, cd, docker,  grep, cut, sort, export%
},emphstyle=[1]{\color{red}\bfseries},%
emph=[2]{%  
    run, -f, -n, -o, -t, -k, -j, -q, -v%
},emphstyle=[2]{\color{orange}\bfseries},%
emph=[3]{%  
    --mount, --workdir, -e%
},emphstyle=[3]{\color{purple}\bfseries},%
emph=[4]{%
    Salmo\_salar.ICSASG\_v2.dna.toplevel.fa.gz, Salmo\_salar.ICSASG\_v2.dna.toplevel.fa,  Salmo\_salar.ICSASG\_v2.dna.toplevel.fa.fai,
    Ssal\_chrm.txt
},emphstyle=[4]{\color{blue}\bfseries},%
emph=[5]{%  
    juettemann\/samtools:latest,  juettemann/genrich:1.0%
},emphstyle=[5]{\color{brown}\bfseries},%
}%

\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}{ %
%  keywords={FOO,BAR,BAZ,ARG}, %
%  otherkeywords={1234,XYZ1234,XYZ1234HelloWorld}, %
alsoletter=.\_-/:,
}%

\begin{lstlisting}[language=mylang]
    cd $dir_atac/ref_genome 
    wget http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-103/fasta/salmo_salar/dna/Salmo_salar.ICSASG_v2.dna.toplevel.fa.gz
    gunzip Salmo_salar.ICSASG_v2.dna.toplevel.fa.gz
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: pdf isn't really suited for such copy&paste, and listings doesn't make it easier. You could try the accsupp package to add some actualtext entry.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @UlrikeFischer! While I unfortunately do not have time for really learning the package, thanks to your hint I found this page 
https://www.monperrus.net/martin/copy-pastable-listings-in-pdf-from-latex
I copied the relevant sections, and everything works perfectly now. 
Vielen Dank & viele Gruesse,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of Ulrike Fischer in the comment section, accsupp was the solution. I added instructions from
https://www.monperrus.net/martin/copy-pastable-listings-in-pdf-from-latex, and now it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ 
upquote=true,
columns=fullflexible,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
literate={*}{{\char42}}1
         {-}{{\char45}}1
         {\ }{{\copyablespace}}1
}

\usepackage[space=true]{accsupp}
\newcommand{\copyablespace}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=00A0}\hphantom{x}\EndAccSupp{}}
```

I only use latex sporadically, my understanding of the system is not deep enough to explain what it does.